# Can't connect to localhost:3000 after creating Rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, ruby, git, ubuntu

I recently installed Ruby and then installed Rails. I used the some tutorial as a guide for installing with the commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git-core curl zlib1g-dev build-essential libssl-dev libreadline-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev python-software-properties libffi-dev nodejs
```

Then using `rbenv`:

```
cd
git clone https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv.git ~/.rbenv
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.bashrc
exec $SHELL

git clone https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build.git ~/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
exec $SHELL

rbenv install 2.4.1
rbenv global 2.4.1
ruby -v
```

It's indicating that ruby is installed properly.

I installed bundler:

```
gem install bundler
```

Configured Git:

```
git config --global color.ui true
git config --global user.name "YOUR NAME"
git config --global user.email "YOUR@EMAIL.com"
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "YOUR@EMAIL.com"`
```

I took the newly generated ssh key and pasted it here:

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

I installed Rails:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs

gem install rails -v 5.1.3

rbenv rehash
```

then to verify the install:

```
rails -v
```

This indicates successful Rails installation.

Then I setup MySQL:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client libmysqlclient-dev
```

Then created a project:

```
rails new myapp -d mysql
```

When creating a database:

```
rake db:create
```

I get

```
rake aborted!
No Rakefile found (looking for: rakefile, Rakefile, rakefile.rb, Rakefile.rb)

(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

When I run

```
rails server
```

and visit `localhost:3000` my browser indicates that it is unable to connect.

I installed MySQL with no password.

What is the issue? I previously installed PHP7, MySQL, and phpMyAdmin on the same system. Could this be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

When running `rake db:create`, make sure you in your app's folder:

```
cd myapp
rake db:create
```

Comment: ,I was already making that and I repeated that step again,but still the same issue. rake aborted!
No Rakefile found (looking for: rakefile, Rakefile, rakefile.rb, Rakefile.rb)

(See full trace by running task with --trace)

Comment: when you do rails new myapp, rails will automatically create all rakefile let me add another clue, after you cd myapp, and then type ls (if you in mac / linux) or dir (if you in windows) you should see list of folder like app,bin,config,db,lib